# Help with rails restful authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I just installed the restful authentication using [this](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication) plugin and when I go to localhost:3000/login
i get this error

> NameError in SessionController#new
>
> uninitialized constant
>   SessionController

Any ideas? please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, if you're just getting started with Rails authentication, I'd highly recommend you use [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic).  Restful Authentication had its time but it generates a lot of code that isn't always clear and it's pretty tough to extend.

If you're set on using Restful Auth, make sure your Session controller is created, the routes are present, and the actions within the session_controller.rb are created.

Comment: AuthLogic is #win over RestfulAuth.

Answer (score 0):

This was mentioned on the [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/67-restful-authentication) site...

> 

Try this (pluralize sessions):

map.resource :session, :controller => 'sessions'

Answer (score 0):

Restful auth had its day. You'll be better off with authlogic. I wrote a little post here on authlogic basics.

http://blog.platform45.com/2009/09/30/user-authentication-with-authlogic